# How to get the id of all the child node UL tags in a UL

Tags: javascript

I know this is a pretty basic question I just seem to be having some issues doing it. I have a HTML structure like below.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class=t2 id=15>
            <li class='item'>a<span class='val'>b</span></li>
            <li class='item'>c<span class='val'>d</span></li>
            <li class='item'>e<span class='val'>f</span></li>
            <li class='item'>parameters : </li>
            <li>
                <ul class=t3 id=16>
                    <li>
                        <ul class=t4 id=17></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ul class=t4 id=18></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the UL with the id of 16 selected and I want to select all its child ul nodes and grab there id. I am able to select the ul with an id of 17 but I cannot grab it's sister node. Here is the JavaScript I am using to get the child nodes.

```
if (document.getElementById(this.toDelete[i]).getElementsByTagName('ul').length >= 1) {
    var tag = document.getElementById(this.toDelete[i]).getElementsByTagName('ul');
        for (var k = 0; k <= tag.length; k++) {
            console.log("tag name: " + tag[k].id + " these will be pushed to Delete");
        }
}
```

So the logic should be, the the selected UL has child ULs get the ID of those ULs and print them to the console.

The above code does not work. I believe that is because it is grabbing the  which does not have a id. But it also if I change it to k < tag.length it works, but still only gets 17 and I want to it get 18 as well.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED, full function. the items array is an array of objects with html and id properties, toDelete is an array with just numbers (ids of items to be deleted. The html in items.html corresponds to one line of html. IE 'ab'. The function is a bit of a mess since I am just trying to get it to work properly. I know I can make it cleaner, that is why I did not post the whole function.

```
deleteItems: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.toDelete.length; i++) {
        console.log("Item to be deleted: " + this.toDelete[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < this.items.length; j++) {
            if (this.items[j].id == this.toDelete[i]) {
                this.items[j] = ""; //this should be a slice
                if (document.getElementById(this.toDelete[i]).getElementsByTagName('ul').length >= 1) {
                    var tag = document.getElementById(this.toDelete[i]).getElementsByTagName('ul');
                    for (var k = 0; k <= tag.length; k++) {
                        console.log("tag name: " + tag[k].id + " these will be pushed to Delete");
                    }
                    this.toDelete.push(document.getElementById(this.toDelete[i]).getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].id);
                    //check to see if it has those there sister nodes. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: numeric IDs are invalid. You should start your IDs with a letter

Comment: Shouldn't there be some quotes in there too? id = "id"

Comment: Also, would you mind setting up a fiddle with the full code?

Comment: @JanDvorak not true, HTML 5 specifications say anything other than a space is fine.

Comment: @user1944367 I don't think IE8 knows the HTML5 spec ;-)

Comment: @Evan here you go, the full code is sort of huge. That's why I did not post everything. Also sorry for the big gross delete function.

Comment: @user1944367 I posted what I think should do the trick, thanks for the update

Comment: Here is a typical case where jQuery would show its muscles, you dont even have to give id:s to the elements.

Comment: @AndersLindén I actually want to avoid JQuery, I think it is really relied on as a crutch way too much. Is JQuery necessary to simply select some DOM items? In my opinion it's not worth loading in some bloated library to do something simple.

Comment: It is not requred, but it makes the code look nice. You can also load it once and let the browser cache it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `children` to get each child node, and then you can check to ensure the found node is a `ul` by using JavaScript's `nodeName`. To be extra safe I used `toLowerCase()` to guarantee that the nodeName looks like *ul* and not *UL*

```
deletedItems();

function deletedItems() {
    var ulChildren = document.getElementById('ul16').children;                
    var childrenLength = ulChildren.length;
alert(childrenLength);    
    for(var i = 0; i < childrenLength; i++){
        if(ulChildren[i].children[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'ul'){
            alert("found one, the id is: " + ulChildren[i].children[0].id);
        }
    }
}
```

## [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKKGA/11/)

Also, I modified your HTML a bit:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class=t2 id=15>
            <li class='item'>a<span class='val'>b</span></li>
            <li class='item'>c<span class='val'>d</span></li>
            <li class='item'>e<span class='val'>f</span></li>
            <li class='item'>parameters : </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="t3" id="ul16">
                    <li>
                        <ul class=t4 id="ul17"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ul class="t4" id="ul18"></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, Evan. I actually ended up with something close to what you suggested. The items array is 100s of lines long and some uls do not have uls inside them, so because of that when they get to this line.
    var ulChildren = document.getElementById('ul16').children; it breaks. Anyways, thanks for your help.